# Does an undead retain its subtypes from when it was alive?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead

I'm specifically interested in whether the Paragon Surge spell can be used after a half-elf (or a custom humanoid race with both human and elf subtypes) became undead (for example by transforming into a lich).

In a similar matter, I'm interested in whether a custom race with the undead type can add those subtypes from its "previous life" for free, since subtypes in general don't seem to be priced within Race Builder.

Answer (score 3):

### Undead almost always lose kind-based subtypes.

#### Kind-based subtypes are almost always replaced by undead templates.

Pathfinder uses the word "kind" in a few places but doesn't explicitly define it (as far as I know), effectively falling back to the 3.5e definition of "kind" as referenced [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135281/64214) by Hey I Can Chan, where it basically meant "a creature-specific subtype" (so, e.g., "human" or "elf" would be a kind but "good" or "extraplanar" would not be, as they aren't subcategories of a specific creature type). References to this use of "kind" can be found in several templates, such as [the skeleton template](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterTemplates.aspx?ItemName=Skeleton):

> **Type:** The creature’s type changes to undead. It retains any subtype except for alignment subtypes (such as good) and **subtypes that indicate kind (such as giant)**. It does not gain the augmented subtype. It uses all the base creature’s statistics and special abilities except as noted here.

This language is used for several other template, such as zombies. [Liches](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterTemplates.aspx?ItemName=Lich) (and a few others, like vampires, ghosts, and mummy lords) define their type change as follows, fully replacing the type without making an exception for retaining their subtype:

> **Type:** The creature's type changes to undead. Do not recalculate BAB, saves, or skill ranks.

[The example lich](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Lich) is explicitly human and has the type "medium undead (augmented humanoid)," with [the example human ghost](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ghost) similarly being "medium undead (augmented humanoid, incorporeal)."

#### Almost every undead lacks a kind-based subtype.

Looking at [every monster](https://www.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?Letter=All), almost every undead creature lacks a kind-based subtype with a few exceptions:

- Vampire-adjacent creatures such as the [vampire lord](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Vampire%20Lord) and [vampire spawn](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterTemplates.aspx?ItemName=Vampire%20Spawn), from the Monster Codex.
- [Trench zombies](https://www.aonprd.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Trench%20Zombie), from Rasputin Must Die!.

Of those creatures, vampire spawn is the only one with a template. Personally, given that the overwhelming majority of undead (including "standard" vampires and zombies) lose kind-based subtypes and that the sole exceptions come from one book and an AP, I chalk them up as errors compared to the 250+ undead without kind-based types.

#### Half-undead get a subtype, undead do not by default.

The race builder explicitly mentions the following:

> Two of the creature types—construct and undead—create interesting player options, but are too expensive if you are trying to create a race within the strictures of the standard power level. [...] When you apply these subtypes to the humanoid type, choose another subtype as the creature's other half. For example, you could make a creature that is humanoid (half-construct, human).

This has an explicit carve-out for a half-undead to be "humanoid (half-undead, elf)," but nothing specifies one way or another as to whether you could optionally tack on additional subtypes to other types. (It actually, as written, wouldn't allow "humanoid (half-undead, human, elf)" to be a half-undead half-elf). The primary reference to subtypes outside the special subtypes is as follows, with no mention of needing or getting to select subtypes for other types:

> The humanoid type requires that you pick at least one subtype for your race, and the outsider (native) type allows you to make a decision about what other plane your race may have ties to.

Overall, since the race builder doesn't specifically mention that you can freely mix and match subtypes — only allowing a single carryover subtype for humanoids with the special subtypes — and given that the vast majority of undead lose kind-based subtypes, the guidance points to not building a custom undead race with a kind-based subtype. Ultimately, the race builder is more of a set of guidelines rather than a strict set of rules for what can or cannot be done to build a custom race: at the end of the day, it's very explicitly supposed to be a collaboration with the GM (assuming you aren't the GM yourself).